# PHP error 1064 : syntax error

Tags: mysql

Currently trying to put a local website online.
Specification:

```
* PHP 7.1
* My SQL 5.5
```

When trying to import my DB I receive the following error message:

> Requête SQL:
>   Base de données :  `vs`
>   Structure de la table `vsc_aps_social_icons`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vsc_aps_social_icons` (
  `si_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `icon_set_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon_display` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_rows` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon_margin` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon_tooltip` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tooltip_background` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tooltip_text_color` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon_animation` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opacity_hover` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icon_details` text,
  `icon_extra` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`si_id`)
) TYPE=InnoDB  AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

MySQL a répondu: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB  AUTO_INCREMENT=3' at line 25

It's the 1st time I put a website online so may your explanations be as complete as possible.
Thanks,
E

Comment: May your question be as complete as possible...

Comment: *Please* for the love of everyone's eyes, *use the preview pane before submitting your question!*  This is a formatting nightmare...

Answer (score 4):

Use `ENGINE = InnoDB` instead of `TYPE = InnoDB`. TYPE was removed in 5.1.